# Remove rows of multidimensional structures

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, structure

I need to remove rows which represent dots of multidimensional structure, which are closest to each other.

For example, if structure is:

```
struct Point dot[100] = {
    {{1, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{2, 2, 2, 2}},
    {{1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3}}
};
```

After applying Euclidean distance formula, distances are:

d12=sqrt((1-2)^2+(1-2)^2+(1-2)^2+(1-2)^2))=2

d13=sqrt((1-1.3)^2+(1-1.3)^2+(1-1.3)^2+(1-1.3)^2)=0.6

d23=sqrt((2-3)^2+(2-3)^2+(2-3)^2+(2-3)^2))=2

Closest points are the ones that represent row1 and row3, and they should be removed from structure.

OUTPUT should be: **(2,2,2,2)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Point {
    double coordinate[100];
};
void remove_closest(struct Point dot[], int n, int dimension){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<dimension-1;j++){
      // 
    }
}
}
int main() {
struct Point dot[100] = {
    {{1, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{2, 2, 2, 2}},
    {{1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3}}
};
 int i,j,dimension=4;
 remove_closest(dot, 3, dimension);

 for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    printf("(");
    for (j=0; j<dimension-1; j++)
        printf("%g,", dot[i].coordinate[j]);
    printf("%g)\n", dot[i].coordinate[dimension-1]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Structures are new to me, and multidimensional array makes it even harder.
Could you help me with this task?

More example of [input/output](https://ibb.co/Lgtj69K)

- Note: auxiliary arrays are not allowed

Comment: I'm not 100% following, but you can't change the size of an array during runtime. So if you mean you actually want to remove some rows and shrink the size, you can't. Other options off the top I can think of 1) `memmove` all data above (below?) the row you're removing to overwrite the row to erase, like Tetris. This will leave an invalid row at the end. 2) Use pointers to point to the rows of interest. 3) Use a linked list instead of array.

Comment: Why do you have `double coordinate[100];` in the struct when it appears you have at most 4 dimensions? Don't you want: `double coordinate[4];` instead? Please edit your question and post _all_ your code in a separate code block. Particularly, the euclidean distance function and how you're calling it in `remove_closest`. What is the `dimension` argument to `remove_closest` supposed to mean?

Comment: @yano I think OP's requirement is to use arrays, maintain a count of number of rows in use. Then, [_two_] rows can be removed by `memmove` in-place, reducing the count as needed. (e.g.) `struct Point dot[100]` defines the _maximum_ number of rows. Currently, only the first 3 are defined.

Comment: well everything I have written is here in code, I don't know how to use Euclidian distance formula with multidimensional array, and with these structures, I don't know how to start even, how many loops I need...

Comment: double coordinate[100] is because my code should work with big arrays, I have just used one structure as example in main function

Comment: @CraigEstey yes, that's it, how could that be implemented, could you post some code as example*

Comment: I'd be glad to post an example, but I'll need a bit more information. If you can't have auxiliary arrays, can you _sort_ the existing array? A given point has 4 dimensions (e.g. `w,x,y,z`). But, can the struct have additional elements? In your example, you have 3 points and remove the two closest. Easy enough. But, if we had 15 points, we could find and remove the two that are closest. So, we have 13 points remaining. Do we repeat this a few times, going down by two each time? Or, is it regardless of the point count, just remove the two closest? Is there more sample input data?

Comment: There's no need to sort array. Struct can only have element `double coordinates[100]`. If we had 15 points, we would have removed 2 and 13 would left, they sorting should be the same as before, just without 2 which were removed

Comment: here's more example of input, output: --> https://ibb.co/Lgtj69K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on all of the criteria, here is what I'd do. I've generalized the code a bit. And I've renamed a few variables to be more descriptive. The code is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// number of elements in an array
#define COUNTOF(_arr)           (sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0]))

// maximum number of dimensions -- adjust to suit
#define MAXDIM      4

struct point {
    double coordinate[MAXDIM];
};

// prtpoint -- print single point
void
prtpoint(const struct point *ptcur,int ndim)
{
    int sep = '(';

    for (int idxdim = 0; idxdim < ndim;  ++idxdim) {
        printf("%c%g",sep,ptcur->coordinate[idxdim]);
        sep = ',';
    }

    printf(")\n");
}

// prtlist -- print all points
void
prtlist(const struct point *points,int npoint,int ndim,const char *title)
{

    if (title != NULL)
        printf("%s: %d\n",title,npoint);

    for (int idxdot = 0;  idxdot < npoint;  ++idxdot)
        prtpoint(&points[idxdot],ndim);
}

double
square(double x)
{

    return x * x;
}

double
euclidean_distance(const struct point *points,int ndim,int idxlo,int idxhi)
{
    double dist = 0.0;
    const struct point *ptlo = &points[idxlo];
    const struct point *pthi = &points[idxhi];

    // sum of the squares of all the dimensions
    for (int idxdim = 0;  idxdim < ndim;  ++idxdim)
        dist += square(ptlo->coordinate[idxdim] - pthi->coordinate[idxdim]);

    dist = sqrt(dist);

    return dist;
}

// remove_closest -- remove closest points
int
remove_closest(struct point *points, int npoint, int ndim)
{
    int minlo = -1;
    int minhi = -1;
    double mindist = 0.0;

    // find the indexes of the two points that have the minimum distance
    for (int idxlo = 0;  idxlo < (npoint - 1);  ++idxlo) {
        for (int idxhi = idxlo + 1;  idxhi < npoint;  ++idxhi) {
            double curdist = euclidean_distance(points,ndim,idxlo,idxhi);

            // (1) grab the first distance we calculate as the minimum
            // (2) get the "best" minimum
            if ((minlo < 0) || (curdist < mindist)) {
                minlo = idxlo;
                minhi = idxhi;
                mindist = curdist;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    // strip the two closest entries
    struct point *ptsrc = points;
    struct point *ptdst = points;
    for (int idxcur = 0;  idxcur < npoint;  ++idxcur, ++ptsrc) {
        // skip either of the two lowest points
        if ((idxcur == minlo) || (idxcur == minhi)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("REMOVE: %d ",idxcur);
            prtpoint(ptsrc,ndim);
#endif
            continue;
        }

        // copy the point to fill the gap
        // NOTE: we _could_ just _always_ do the copy but doing this
        // conditionally is a speedup (i.e. avoid unnecessary copies)
        if (ptdst != ptsrc)
            *ptdst = *ptsrc;

        ++ptdst;
    }

    npoint -= 2;

    return npoint;
}

void
dolist(struct point *points,int npoint,int ndim)
{

    // should never happen [because if we get here, the compiler _should_
    // have complained in the definition of the array we've been passed]
    if (ndim > MAXDIM)
        exit(9);

    prtlist(points,npoint,ndim,"Before");
    npoint = remove_closest(points,npoint,ndim);
    prtlist(points,npoint,ndim,"After");
}

void
test01(void)
{
    struct point points[] = {
        {{1, 1, 1, 1}},
        {{2, 2, 2, 2}},
        {{1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3}}
    };

    dolist(points,COUNTOF(points),4);
}

void
test02(void)
{
    struct point points[] = {
        // NOTE: duplicate points aren't handled the way this example implies
#if 0
        {{1, 1, 1, 1}},
#endif
        {{1, 1, 1, 1.00}},
        {{1, 1, 1, 1.2}},
        {{1, 1, 1, 1.145}},
        {{1, 1, 1, 1.31}},
        {{1, 1, 1, 1.1}},
    };

    dolist(points,COUNTOF(points),4);
}

int
main(void)
{

    test01();
    test02();

    return 0;
}
```

---

After compiling with `-DDEBUG`, here is the program output:

```
Before: 3
(1,1,1,1)
(2,2,2,2)
(1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3)
REMOVE: 0 (1,1,1,1)
REMOVE: 2 (1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3)
After: 1
(2,2,2,2)
Before: 5
(1,1,1,1)
(1,1,1,1.2)
(1,1,1,1.145)
(1,1,1,1.31)
(1,1,1,1.1)
REMOVE: 2 (1,1,1,1.145)
REMOVE: 4 (1,1,1,1.1)
After: 3
(1,1,1,1)
(1,1,1,1.2)
(1,1,1,1.31)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> thank you very much, could you just modify without typedef? –
> devec

Well, if you really wish ;-)

The original was:

```
typedef struct point {
    double coordinate[MAXDIM];
} point_t;
```

Note that if I wanted to be a "smarty pants", I *could* do this with a `#define` and still fulfill the requirement ;-):

```
struct point {
    double coordinate[MAXDIM];
};
#define point_t struct point
```

But, I've edited the above code to use just the normal `struct`. All I did was just do the simple `struct` definition. Then, just globally change all `point_t` into `struct point`. So, really not too difficult. (e.g.) Change:

```
double
euclidean_distance(const point_t *points,int ndim,int idxlo,int idxhi)
```

Into:

```
double
euclidean_distance(const struct point *points,int ndim,int idxlo,int idxhi)
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Although I touched on the briefly in the comments for `test02` [taken from your *linked* data example], the code at present doesn't handle exact duplicate points too well. The data was the same for all points in all dimensions *except* the last one:

```
1
1.1
1.00
1.2
1.145
1.31
```

1. As present, if we have two *identical* points, these are the ones that would be removed (i.e. their distance is 0.0). So, we'd remove `1` and `1.00`
2. This is contrary to your second example where the `1.1` and `1.00` points were removed.
3. Even if we excluded/ignored points that are the same, it would be the *first* copy of `1.00` that would match. That is, the `1` point and the `1.1` point would be removed.
4. I punted on this a bit by just removing one of the points that was identical in the input data.

After considering the above:

1. In your example, the two points [you] removed were `1.1` and `1.00`. The distance is: `0.1`
2. But, my code removed `1.1` and `1.145`. The distance is: `0.045`

So, I think your example was incorrect and you removed the wrong points. You may have to decide if this is a relevant issue for you.

Comment: thank you very much, could you just modify without typedef?